# Notification BigPictureStyle EXPANDED on pre 6.0 and post devices

Tags: android, notifications

I read a lot of threads about this but have not found any solution for this.
I'm using FMC notification and displaying them with following method:

```
    public static void sendNotification(Context context, int id, String title, String bitmapUrl) {

    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(bitmapUrl);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_POST_DETAIL, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = context.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setStyle(
                            new NotificationCompat
                                    .BigPictureStyle()
                                    .bigPicture(bitmap)
                                    .bigLargeIcon(bitmap)
                                    .setBigContentTitle(title)

                    )
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)

                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(id, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

I read a lot of threads about this but have not found any solution.

I have read that only the notification at the top of the stack should be shown expanded.
In devices pre 6.0, to be exact a huawei with 5.0.2, this always works well the first notification is shown already expanded.
In devices post 6.0, to be exact, a huawei with 6.0.1, the nofitiche of my app are always shown collapsed and only if swipe the notification down it is expanded.

I tried other code examples, I read the android documentation but I did not solve the problem.
I also used the custom notification inflating a separate layout xml but they have different behavior in the two android versions and show the same problem.

I do not understand why other apps like youtube for example show notifications expanded correctly, so it means that the way is ....

Could anyone clarify if there is a way to show at least the first expanded notification, which works on all versions at least from 5.0 and up?
Thanks